# Flutter AlertDIalog in BlocBuilder

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

I am using BlocBuilder to create an account with firebase but it shows me the error message as a text, I need to show it in an alertdialog

BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
builder: (_, state) {
return Form(
key: _formKey,
child: Padding(

```
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                                              child: Column(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                  children: [
                                                  if (state is AuthSigningIn)
                                              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      if (state is AuthError)
                                        Text(
                                          state.message,
                                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24),
                                        ),

                                      const SizedBox(height: 8),
                                      TextField(
                                      controller: _emailController,
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),

                                      ),
```

In this code I need a ShowDialog
if (state is AuthError)
Text(
state.message,
style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24),
),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BlocConsumer<AuthCubit, AuthState>( 
    listener: (_, state) {
if (state is AuthError){
customDialog(context,Text(
                                          state.message,
                                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 24),
                                        ),)
}
                                        
}
    builder: (_, state) { return Form( key: _formKey, child: Padding(

                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
                                              child: Column(
                                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                  children: [
                                                  if (state is AuthSigningIn)
                                              const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                                      

                                      const SizedBox(height: 8),
                                      TextField(
                                      controller: _emailController,
                                      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),

                                      ),

    customDialog(BuildContext context, Widget child,
        {double dialogHeight = 500, double dialogWidth = 400}) {
      return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Dialog(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
          ),
          child: Container(
            height: height(dialogHeight),
            width: width(dialogWidth),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: child
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```

You can't use a dialog in a blocbuilder or at least the process of doing it is long,

So you use a bloc consumer and in the listener parameter you can put all of your snack bars and dialogs.

Comment: Thanks but I use blocBuilder and when I place that line the error comes out 

"The element type 'Set<Future<dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"

Comment: Oh wait you can't use a blocBuilder my bad.

Comment: And other snackbar type window can be used

Comment: I have editted the code

Comment: Upvote the answer so you get to help other people.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu valiosa ayuda pude resolver ese problema...Thank you